# Is it possible to destroy your own car and get money from the scrapyard for it?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I have a few cars in my garage that I necessarily want anymore and I don't know how to get rid of them.

Comment: Can you sell them at the pay and spray in single player ?

Answer (score 3):

You can sell unneeded cars to Los Santos Customs. Press the Down key on your controller or keyboard to highlight the “Sell” option, and press the “Select” button to view the price of the car. Hitting Select again will sell the car.